# C++ class using a variable from private class

Tags: c++, function, class

I am trying to use a variable from the private class and both add and subtract from it at different times, first add 5 to it 5 times then subtract 5 from it 5 times and each time i have to display its value. Currently i have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class car {
  private:
    int year;
    string make;
    int speed;

  public:
    void StoreInfo(int y, string m, int s);

    int getSpeed() { return speed; }

    int accelerate() { speed += 5; }

    int brake() { speed -= 5; }
};

void car::StoreInfo(int y, string m, int s) {
    year = y;
    make = m;
    speed = s;
}

car fillFields() {
    car Filler;
    int year; // Local variables to hold user input
    string make;
    int speed = 0;

    // Get the data from the user
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    cin >> year;
    cout << "Enter make: ";
    cin.get(); // Move past the '\n' left in the
               // input buffer by the last input
    getline(cin, make);
    cout << "The current speed is " << speed << endl;

    Filler.StoreInfo(year, make, speed);
    return Filler;
}

int main() {
    car numbers = fillFields();
    car::accelerate();

    return 0;
}
```

This code accepts the input but does not work after that i realize that the car::accelerate() line in the main is incorrect now but how would i use it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried `numbers.accelerate()`. `accelerate` is not static and needs an object

Comment: just tried it and it did not add any output for some reason, i even added a return of the speed variable after i added it by 5 in the public function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `accelerate` and `brake` do not return any value so you can make them `void`

```
void accelerate() { speed += 5; }
void brake() { speed -= 5; }
```

`accelerate` is non-static member function and needs an object so you need to call it like:

```
numbers.accelerate();
```

And for example change your `main` function like this to `accerelate` once and then `brake` and see the speed:

```
int main() {
    car numbers = fillFields();

    numbers.accelerate();   // +5
    cout << "The current speed is " << numbers.getSpeed() << endl;

    numbers.brake();        // -5
    cout << "The current speed is " << numbers.getSpeed() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

> Enter year: Enter make: The current speed is 0
>
> The current speed is 5
>
> The current speed is 0

<kbd>[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hchRmUvDYLiolGxG)</kbd>

You can replace `car::StoreInfo` with a constructor, because it does what the constructors are meant for. And don't forget to initialize your variables.

Comment: Thanks for this it worked, i was confused with how to call it correctly and you got it right. Appreciate it!

Comment: Nitpick:  Unless a function has a *forever* loop, it will return.  Functions don't need to return values, and those that don't have a return type of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers.accelerate();
```

You are not using any static data. You could rename numbers variable if you want.

Comment: i tried this and changed the public function to return speed after adding 5 to it and i just get no output, any idea ehy?

Comment: cout the speed after you call accelerate... You are calling cout before accelerate is called